Simplification of minimizing $f(x)$ with constraint $x<a$ by ignoring constraint
For the optimization problem: $$ \min f(x) \text{ s.t } x<a$$
where $f(x)$ is a convex function.
Can I simplify this problem by ignoring the constraint and then check the feasibility of the solution, which mean minimize $f(x)$ without considering $x<a$. What's the difference between this method and those traditional optimizing methods like Penalty/Barrier method?
Is there any theoretic support for this method (ignoring constraint) in optimization theory?

if $x \in \mathbb{R}$, you can ignore the constraint, and set the solution to $a$ if the constraint is violated.
For higher dimensions, in general, you can't do it. Successive projected gradient descent is fine.
The penalty/barrier method relaxes the constraint(s), and solves a sequence of unconstrained minimization problems via e.g., 1st- or 2nd- order method.
